# Installing Wordpress with MongoDB

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mongodb, content-management-system

Is it possible to create a wordpress site with mongodb ? can i use a mongodb instead of mysql ? i already tried and wordpress returns an error message "Error Establishing database connection"

Comment: Not out of the box. A quick search yielded out a couple of unmaintanied plugins. The real question is, why would you want that? Is there a particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

No. Reason, mongo is a non SQL database, there is many database queries on the source code designed for MySQL and MariaDB (wordpress default databases) and many plugins are counting on that database by default